# iPhone - How to save image with custom name in iPhone album?

Tags: iphone, camera, nsfilemanager

I am doing one application which is related to iPhone album and photos. My requirement is to save my UIImageView image in to the photo album with custom name for example "myImage.png". I know how to save the photo in album but I need to know how to specify the custom name.

After saving the photo with custom name I need to get the photo with the same name when i select the same photo from the camera in my application. Right i am able to get the photo name when i select the photo, but for all the photo it is showing the photo as asset 2. What is the solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [iphone-camera-roll-picture-naming-reset-after-firmware-update](http://www.celifornia.com/blog/2008/03/26/iphone-camera-roll-picture-naming-reset-after-firmware-update/) link. it shows how update images names.